# Standalone document of a fixed width

Tags: tikz-pgf, width, standalone

My publisher wants my images to be able to be loaded at 100% scale so that font sizes aren't scaled, but requires widths to be one of 20mm, 44mm, 68mm, 82mm or 140mm to correspond to the column widths (20mm+4mm gap).
I have several standalone images with text that would need to fit one of these measurements.
What's the best way to do this?  It seems to be complicated by the need to use different compilers. (I am using XeLaTeX)
Here is an example file which has a generated width of 63 mm that I would like to be 44mm.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}%RGB Definitions
\definecolor{PG-Chem}{RGB}{5,114,118}

\usepackage {tikz}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}

\begin{document}

\begin {tikzpicture}[yscale=0.05]
%Define Isotopes
    \pgfmathsetmacro {\isotopeAmass}{10}    
    \pgfmathsetmacro {\isotopeBmass}{11}
    \pgfmathsetmacro {\isotopeAabundance}{19.97}
    \pgfmathsetmacro {\isotopeBabundance}{80.03}
    \pgfmathsetmacro {\xmin}{\isotopeAmass-2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro {\xmax}{\isotopeBmass+2}       

%draw Grid & axes
      \draw [thick, ->] (\xmin,0)--(\xmin,100) node [midway, anchor=south, rotate=90, yshift=0.5cm]{\% Abundance}; %y-axis
    \draw [thick, ->] (\xmin,0)--(\xmax,0) node [midway, anchor=north,yshift=-0.5cm]{mass/charge ratio}; %x-axis
    
        \foreach \x in {\xmin,...,\xmax}
            \draw (\x,-0.75) -- (\x ,0) node[below,anchor=north,yshift=-3pt]{\x}; %x-axis tick marks

    \foreach \y in {10,20,...,100}
            \draw (\xmin-0.1, \y cm) -- (\xmin, \y cm) node[above,anchor=east]{\y}; %y-axis tick marks
    
    \foreach \g in {10,20,...,100}
        \draw[gray!50,very thin] (\xmin, \g ) -- (\xmax, \g ); %horizontal grid
   
%Draw spectrum
    \draw[line width=2pt,PG-Chem] (\isotopeAmass,0)--(\isotopeAmass,\isotopeAabundance) node [above, anchor=south]{\isotopeAabundance \%};
    \draw[line width=2pt,PG-Chem] (\isotopeBmass,0)--(\isotopeBmass,\isotopeBabundance)node [above, anchor=south]{\isotopeBabundance \%};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

By `standalone` as any other document class you cannot prescribe images widths. Their widths are always define by image itself.

In your case seems that the closest what you like to achieve is use `pgfplots` package for drawing of diagram. Using it you can quite simple prescribe images widths by `axis` option ˙width=`. Beside this, using` pgfplots` the diagram code is simpler and more consistent:

```
% XeTeX
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\definecolor{PG-Chem}{RGB}{5,114,118}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[width=82mm,    % <--- width of image
    axis lines=left,
    axis line style = {thick},
    ybar,
    bar width=2pt,          % you may define wider width: 4pt or even more
    ymajorgrids,
    xlabel = {\% Abundance},
    ylabel = {mass/charge ratio},
    xmin=8, xmax=13,
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
    ytick distance = 10,
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\,\%},
    ]
%Draw spectrum
\addplot [draw=PG-Chem, fill=PG-Chem] coordinates {  (10, 19.97) (11, 80.03) };
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]